# Date and Time in datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datetime, datagridview

somebody help me with the problem that every time i save or update a data the date is working fine but the time is always 12:00AM. the time should be the time when I input the data and be saved into the database.

this is my code for the update

```
        Dim i As Short
    con.Open()
    Using com As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("UPDATE Information set FiveS_Date = '" & DateTimePicker1.Text & "',FiveS_Score = '" & TextBox2.Text & "',FiveS_Total = '" & TextBox3.Text & "' ,FiveS_Percentage = '" & TextBox4.Text & "' WHERE Id='" & id & "'", con)
        i = com.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
    con.Close()
    If (i > 0) Then


        MsgBox("Training updated successfully", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    End If
```

please help.

Answer (score 1):

You should use parameters to avoid the problem of data conversion when you use ADO.NET. This helps you also with different cultures in your application.

Anyway, `DateTimePicker1.Value`will give you also the time, but if you select a date which is different from default value of DateTimePicker (which is Now), then DateTimePicker will always give you the time "12:00". You have to format it to show time also and to have the possibility to set it (example "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm").

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `DateTimePicker1.Text` to `DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString`

`.Text` just returns what is visible (date only) whereas `.Value` returns the current time as well as the date displayed.

Comment: casting the datetime value to string will only cause other problems. Why not just use datetime types in both database and code?

Comment: @AlexB. Thanks for your comment, I was being slightly lazy answering the question re the 12:00 time stamp without addressing the bigger issue.

Answer (score 0):

To insert time into database you need to use

```
DateTimePicker1.Value
```

instead of

```
DateTimePicker1.Text
```

Comment: `But .value will provide the date in System format` - No. Value will give the datetime value without any format since **dates have no format!**. When dealing with databases and dates one should always use datetime types instead of string casting horrors.

Comment: So, Alex, what exactly you are asking?

Comment: @AlexB. is saying that `you have to provide date into either ... date format into ms-sql query` is wrong.  The only way to worry about a format is convert to string.  The NET dbProviders are perfectly capable of accepting a DateTime and saving it to the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
FiveS_Date ='" + DateTime.Parse(datetxt.Text).ToString("dd/MM/yyy") +"'
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters, `DateTimePicker1.Text` will only give you the String that is displayed in the DateTimePicker, by default the DateTimePickers format will only show you the Date and by default the time will be 12:00 AM. You can change the DateTimePicker format to show time by changing the Format field in the Properties Window of the DateTimePicker to Time. 
[DateTimePicker to Time format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytKnm.jpg)

Or by your sentence you want to save the date selected combined with the time you saved the data to the database, just make a new DateTime variable and insert the DateTimePicker Dates as values to that variable and the time from DateTime.Now() function which will return the current date and time.

```
Dim now As DateTime = DateTime.Now()
Dim myDate = new DateTime(DateTimePicker1.Value.Year, DateTimePicker1.Value.Month, DateTimePicker1.Value.Day, now.Hour, now.Minute, now.Second, now.Millisecond)
```